# Screen capture on failure (Mac OS using Cucumber/Capybara/Selenium-webdriver for Android & iOS)

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, webdriver, capybara, selenium-webdriver

There seems to be a lot of information on screen capture on failure when using Selenium-webdriver however a lot of it differs and all (of what i've tried) does not work. I am testing on iOS and android using Capybara/web-driver. I understand that when using Capybara it has the capabilities of screen capture by accessing the underlying selenium-driver for example page.driver.browser.save_screenshot('file.png').

An example of my code:

```
 After do |scenario|
    if(scenario.failed?)
      page.driver.browser_save_screenshot("html-report/#{scenario._id_}.png")
      embed("#{scenario._id_}.png", "image/png", "SCREENSHOT")
    end
  end
```

The above correctly creates the HTML report however the screenshot is missing. From doing a bit of research it seems like it may be because I am using a scenario outline and its not supported? At least thats what ive found with Watir-webdriver.

Has anyone actually managed to get this working? Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code working with a Scenario and am about to refactor to a Scenario Outline (so I haven't tried a solution I found [here](http://twofourone.blogspot.com/2011/04/making-your-cukes-more-awesomer-with.html)). HTH.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I also tried this a while back. And this must work however I've not managed to get this working as I've spent way too much time on it than I should have. I suspect its my configurations, hopefully soon ill find the time to crack it. Let me know if you have any joy and good luck!